# Asking name to be taken off a paper

Tags: paper-submission, authorship, collaboration, data, reproducible-research

I am asking about the etiquette for getting my name taken off a paper. In grad school I did a collaboration with a PI and the results were limited but okay and I used a very specific microscope to take the images. (The animal I work on has thick tissues and can really only be imaged on the confocal.). The PI wanted to redo the experiment using two replicates so that we can have images all from the same microscope so it can be uniform meaning that I have to use a different scope for the condensed repeated experiments. The new images are so blurry and do not convince me that the experiment is working this go round let alone will they convince anyone else. The PI even tried working with the scope and my animal and concluded the images are subpar. I feel like if the data isn't working this go round in the new environment and the new equipment and I feel like if it isn't reproducing the way I want the right thing to do it to bow out and take my name off (or ask to be given credit for other parts of the manuscript I have worked on).

Idk I just feel meh about my part of the data and not sure how to express that without coming off flaky.

Comment: I think you can mention that you don't feel comfortable. Say it in a diplomatic way, maybe that you would have expected more from your own work and are not happy with it. Be honest without blaming others. You could still just end up in the acknowledgements. Should be OK if you are not the first author

Comment: Do you mean just not listing you as an author, or removing your name completely?

Comment: Well I worked on other imaging aspects of this paper outside of my animal so I would be okay with being in the acknowledgments. But my area of the collaboration was done just me so I feel as though my name should be removed completely as to not bring down the level of science in the manuscript. It sucks but I don't want to put my reputation into question let alone anyone elses

Comment: @Buffy What is the difference between not listing and removing completely?

Comment: @AzorAhai, not being acknowledged within the paper is more extreme than not being a co-author.

Comment: @buffy I definitely don't want to cause issues by taking my name completely off but I guess my thoughts were if the experiment wasn't behaving the same way in this new environment then it is considered not reproducible. But maybe that is not a correct assumption

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion, actually, is that you *don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good*. You aren't satisfied with what you did. Fine. But something was learned because of it. Better.

I'd let it go. If the PI thinks you are a co-author then defer to their experience and judgement. You haven't set science back because you tackled a difficult problem and weren't able to reach a perfect conclusion. That is, in fact, the nature of scientific research.

But if you really don't want to be co-author, just say that. It should be fine. However, if you also don't want to be listed at all, even in acknowledgements, then you leave the others with a serious dilemma. They will have to write the paper in such a way as to avoid plagiarism of your work, if you won't let it be attributed to you. That seems to me to be the worst outcome. Something is known that wasn't previously, but it becomes difficult to let the world advance upon it.

Comment: Thank you! I have a meeting over Zoom with the PI tomorrow where I will share my current images along with my concerns. I just had concerns that if my section of the manuscript couldn't be reproduced by others using different microscopes than a confocal it might be damaging. But I do state clearly in the methods that a confocal is the microscope I used to carry out all of the original research so.